# Apache deny access to an specific file

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian

I'd like to deny access to /arch.1, but not to for example /dir1/arch.1

What I've tried is:

```
<FilesMatch "^(arch.1|arch.2)$">
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

but it match every file any_dir/arch.1 and using ^/ in the beginning is not working. I don't want to use a .htaccess file.

Could you help me please?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you review the relatively good documentation on access control in http://httpd.apache.org.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong directive. You want [`<DirectoryMatch>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directorymatch).
Related: [How directory, location and files directives work](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html).